# Error when calling void function with <set> operator

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass a **string** and and an **empty set** into my function. Then I would like to call the function in my main and print all of the elements in the set.

This is my function code:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;
#include<algorithm>
using std::set_union; using std::copy;
#include<iterator>
using std::inserter; using std::ostream_iterator;
#include<string>
using std::string;
#include<set>
using std::set;

void removing(const string &word, set<string> &result) {
    string del_word = word;
    char erased_l;

    for(int i = 0; i < del_word.length(); i++) {
        erased_l = word[i];
        del_word.erase(0, 1);
        del_word = erased_l + del_word;
    }
}
```

Below is my main code where I call the function:

```
int main (){
    set<string> jump = {};

    set<string> del = removing("axiom", jump);
    for (string ele:del) {
        cout << ele << endl;
    }
 }
```

I get the following error:

```
No viable conversion from 'void' to 'set<std::__1::string>' (aka 'set<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >')
```

The error is in line 16:

```
    set<string> del = removing("axiom", jump);
```

**My code is trying to accomplish:**
If I pass in axiom, then I would like my string set to have {xiom, aiom, axom, axim, axio}. So remove first letter, keep rest of the word. Then remove second letter, keep rest of the word, etc...

Comment: You can't convert `void` to `set`; just pass the `set` reference and don't try to assign the return value to anything. Also, your removing function doesn't do anything with `result`. What is this code supposed to accomplish?

Comment: You get that error for which line?

Comment: @Slava For line 16 in my main. set<string> del = deletes("axiom", jump);

Comment: Put that into question not in comment

Comment: You function `removing()` declared as return `void` but you try to assign it's result to `del` what do you expect?

Comment: @ggorlen Okay I have updated my post!

Comment: @Slava Thanks for the input! I realize that void does not return an output, however, I would still like to output the contents within my set. An empty set and a word is passed in, and the set is modified to a set with strings within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary issues include:

1. The return value of a `void` function can't be assigned to a `set`, hence your compiler error. Your design is to pass a reference to an empty result `set` into the `removing` function and have it populated with the result data, so you can remove the assignment here.
2. Nothing is added to your `result` inside your `removing` function, so it starts empty and ends empty after the function call.

Here's a working version:

```
void removing(const string &word, set<string> &result) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        result.insert(word.substr(0, i) + word.substr(i + 1, word.length()));
    }
}

int main () {
    set<string> jump = {};
    removing("axiom", jump);

    for (string ele : jump) {
        cout << ele << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
aiom
axim
axio
axom
xiom
```

Having said that, it's not clear to me why `result` should be a parameter to the function. If you're only planning on using it to store this particular result, this design seems much cleaner from the perspective of the caller:

```
set<string> removing(const string &word) {
    set<string> result;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        result.insert(word.substr(0, i) + word.substr(i + 1, word.length()));
    }

    return result;
}

int main () {
    set<string> jump = removing("axiom");

    for (string ele : jump) {
        cout << ele << endl;
    }
}
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/IdealLightFlash)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have just started working with void functions so this was very helpful. I'll try to be more descriptive in my question next time.